# Get details from Get Response API

Tags: postgresql, python-requests, getresponse

I'm using Magento and backend as postgresql with python.I have a requirement like getting the details of abandon cart details of customers and would like to insert that details to my data warehouse using Get response API.

So can you please provide some recommendations or suggestions on how this can be done?

Thanks and Best Regards
Lins

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this?